# Casting to Integer in Java when using type double

Tags: java, integer, double

I have this simple code and I need to understand why the right side of the equation has been casted to Integer before getting the result in type `double`.
The answer here is `1.0` so I don't understand why it's not `1.5`.

```
int x = 2;
double y = 1 + 1/x;
System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: The right side is not cast to `Integer`, it already is an integer.  The cast only happens at the very end of the equation.  I guess another way to say this is that order of operations and precedence matter in auto-casting.  So the cast happens at the `=`, and the other operations `/` and `+` have higher precedence and go first, operating on an `int`.

Comment: ok I got it now. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

simply update your code as following since you are dealing with doubles.

```
int x = 2;
double y = 1 + 1.0/x;
System.out.println(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice: double y = 1 + 1/x;

Modify: double y = 1 + 1.0/x;

You'll get 1.5

Answer (score 1):

here x is an int and 1 is also an int so calculation is done in int and so you are getting the answer as 1.0. To get as 1.5 you have to typecast 1 to double as 1.0. Then you will get as 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant was: why the value of 'x' on the right-hand side has not been '***promoted***' to a double?

First, change the second line to :

```
double y = 1 + (double) 1 / x;
//or
double y = 1 + 1.0 / x;
```

**Details:**

Simply for most computers to perform arithmetic operations operands must be of identical data types.

The cast operator **(double)** performs **explicit conversion** of its operand to double, then the variable *' x '* will be **implicitly converted** to a double which is called **promotion**.

*also* in the second line ***1.0*** is already a floating-point **constant** so you can guess that this is the same as before, that is a promotion to the variable *'x'* will occur.

What you have done in **your code** is called ***Integer Division*** meaning that the fractional part of the division will be lost (truncated). Note that the fractional part is lost before it is assigned to the variable y.

You may have some intuition now on why we didn't write the code like that:

```
double y = 1.0 +  1 / x;
```

clearly, *(1 / x)* is still **integer division** ...hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Like user markspace noted in a comment, the integer division happens because `/` has a higher order of precedence than `=`, which means that the division takes place first in the statement.

```
double y = 1 + (1/2); // Both 1 and 2 are integers at the time of operation.

// The above equation is the same as

double y = 1 + 0; // 1/2 equals 0 because integer division just keeps the integer value
                  // and gets rid of the value's decimal part.
```

Similar to what the other answers have shown, you can do something like one of the following:

```
double y = 1 + 1.0/x;
// Or
double y = 1 + 1/(double)x;
```

Just for simplicity, when I use integer literals when assigning `double` values, I just make all the integers have the `.0` part. For example, instead of `1`, I would always put `1.0`. That way, you will never accidentally get unexpected results because of unwanted integer division.

Check out [this page in the Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for the order of precedence for operators in Java.